# Change the labels of a 3d plot using R plotly

Tags: r, 3d, plotly

I created following 3d plot using plotly in R.

```
 library(plotly)
    library(MASS)
    mu_v=c(0.5,0.4,0.5,0.2)
sigma_m=matrix(data = c(1,0.5,0.7,0.4,0.5,1,0.8,0.9,0.7,0.8,1,0.5,0.4,0.9,0.5,1),nrow = 4,byrow = T)
data1=mvrnorm(  10000,mu = mu_v , Sigma = sigma_m )
data1=as.data.frame(data1)
colnames(data1)=c("X1","X2","X3","X4")
plot_ly(x=~X1, y=~X2, z=~X3, type="scatter3d", color=~(X4), mode="markers",data = data1
          , marker = list(
             size    = 5,
             opacity = 10)) %>% layout(plot_bgcolor = "#bababa")
```

[image]

Is there a way to change the labels of axis and the coloring variable ? Also Can I change the background of the xy,yz and xz surface and increase the plotting area?

**Update**

I tried to edit the legend and change the background color as follows:

```
plot_ly(x=~X1, y=~X2, z=~X3, type="scatter3d", color=~(X4), mode="markers",data = data1
          , marker = list(
             size    = 5,
             opacity = 10)) %>% 
  layout(scene = list(legend = list(title = "legend"),plot_bgcolor='#e5ecf6'))
```

But it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option to address your first 2 questions (change x/y/z axis and color legend titles).

```r
plot_ly(
    x = ~X1, 
    y = ~X2, 
    z = ~X3, 
    type = "scatter3d", 
    mode = "markers",
    data = data1,
    marker = list(
        color = ~X4, 
        colorbar = list(title = "Legend"),    # Change colour legend title
        colorscale = "Blues",                 # Change colour palette
        size = 5,
        opacity = 10)) %>%
    layout(
        plot_bgcolor = "#bababa",
        scene = list(
            xaxis = list(title = "Axis 1"),   # Change x/y/z axis title
            yaxis = list(title = "Axis 2"),
            zaxis = list(title = "Axis 3")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  When I couldn't change the color palette to a new one when I use your code. For an example, the colors wont change when I use colors = "Blues"

Comment: @student_R123 You need to use `colorscale` inside `marker = list(...)` to change the palette. I've made an edit.